# Parsing CSV with AWK, returning fields to bash var with line breaks

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, scripting, csv

I have to migrate a password database (Keepass) by using a csv file of it, to a new application by using its API. The API is updated with post requests, those needs JSON data format.
What I need to do is to use the KeePass CSV to export the passwords and other pieces of information linked to it to the API. I decided todo a script using bash and awk.


The columns of the csv file are arranged like this :

```
"Group","Title","Username","Password","URL","Notes","TOTP","Icon","Last Modified","Created"
```

The field "notes" is multiline because some of the comments have line breaks into them.

```
"That's an important note, <br/>
some extra infos <br/>
concerning a password"
```

Here's an example of the API request to post the data, the data field is in JSON format :

*I didn't put all the needed fields on this request but you can already see how it would work. Some of the field names are different because the KeePass and the API fields name are differently made*

```
var1=name
var2=my.name
var3=password456

curl -s --request PUT -u username123:password123 -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' https://tpm.mydomain.com/index.php/api/v5/passwords/1659.json --data-binary @- <<DATA
{
"name": "$var1",
"username": "$var2",
"password": "$var3"
}
DATA
```

I have planned to parse my CSV file field by field and then when I finish to parse the row, I do my API request to post the password in the database. Then I do this for every remaining rows.

To process the CSV I find the AWK language, it seems very handy and quite useful for my situation. I've come with multiple testing on my file with the gsub command, helping me to replace the line breaks (\n). I don't really know how to go further. Here's some of them (only the first work :

```
cat keepass.csv | awk NF=NF RS=/\n/ OFS=\n
cat keepass.csv |awk 'BEGIN {RS=","}{gsub("/\n/","",$0); print $0}'
cat keepass.csv | awk 'BEGIN {RS=""}{gsub(/\n/,"",$6); print $0}'
```

I also know that you can share bash var by adding -v after awk. Here's the closest code I could have.

```
awk -v RS='"\n' -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*' '{
print "Row n°", NR, ""
for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
sub(/^"/, "", $i)
printf "Field %d, value=[%s]\n", i, $i
}} keepass.csv
```

What I am looking for, would be a command to parse any column of my csv by taking in account the multilines notes and input them into the global var of bash in JSON format.

I think you need to structure it by doing something like :

```
awk -v 'BEGIN{parsing and replacing keeping '\n' of notes}
if end of row,
return boolean to bash for processing the API requests, wait,
restart the loop}''
```

I'm new to scripting, I think it can be done in only a few lines but I'm unsure on how to proceed. I can change the language to python if needed and I can add some tools to my code.

Comment: Do you _need_ to do it in awk or can you use a dedicated csv parser?

Comment: `awk` isn't great for parsing CSV files, because it doesn't know anything about quoted fields. If you use a language with proper CSV support (e.g., Python's [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module), you'll end up with a much more effective solution. [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/) is a command line tool for parsing CSV files that might be helpful.

Comment: @larsks Do you think it is easier in python ? Because I could either change to python or just add csvkit to my script, I'm just unsure if it's better or just as the same for a some few lines of script. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: What is easier depends on what _you_ find easier. Everything is easy if you know how to do it :)

Comment: Your question seems to focus on parsing the multi-line `notes` field.  Assuming this is _easy_ to parse, what would you want to do with the data? With [the csvkit tools](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), it's trivial to convert the CSV to JSON (with `csvjson`), pull out a given column (with `csvcut`), grep for a particular record (`csvgrep`), etc. but nowhere in your question do you actually say what it is you want to do with the data. An example would be nice to see.

Comment: At first I assumed that I could just use the var of AWK and do a curl to the API to post the
 passwords but I didn't realize that I needed to convert the csv data to JSON. I edited my question, hope it's clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multi line is a feature of a CSV cell, and you can use an utility that is CSV aware as [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/).

As examples, if you have [this CSV](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aborruso/8cdffab40be847dca6162cdf72932617/raw/afebc7dfe21ef70d9c1d1c6950a2708c7e74e2ff/acr.csv) you can run

- `mlr --csv cut -f fieldA acr.csv` to cut the first column
- `mlr --icsv --ojson cut -f fieldA acr.csv` to cut the first column and convert all to `JSON`

```
[
  {
    "fieldA": "That's an important note,\nsome extra infos\nConcerning a password\nIpsum"
  },
  {
    "fieldA": "hello"
  }
]
```

As you can see Miller is aware of cell carriage return ([RFC4180](https://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc?rfc=4180#gsc.tab=0) compliant).

Below an image of the sample input file.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

> The field "notes" is multiline

No! CSV does not support multi-line. Absolutely not.

There are two common approaches if you need to store a multi-line string in CSV.

1. Change the `\n` character in the original string to something other. Usually it is just a two-letter "\n" string.
2. Change the record delimiter from `\n` into some other character which will not appear in the string. Often it is something like `\x01`.

The first approach would require some additional pre- and post-conversion, but pretty reliable.

The second - works very fine and easy, but not all CSV-able application can change record delimiter, and there is always a possibility that the character you used as record delimiter would appear inside a field.

If by some reason you cannot recreate the file and make it a proper CSV, I would suggest to go with a loop:

```
while read row
 if row has 6 fields ("Notes" is a 6th field)
   do
     append "\n" to it
     append next row to it
   repeat until the working row has 10 fields
   export the work row to output file
 end if
end while
```

Any language can do it (even `bash`).

Comment: CSV supports quoted multi-line fields. Any CSV parser would be able to read that `note` data. See page two of [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=4180#gsc.tab=0).

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not true. The CSV is so 'easy' that almost no one who writes an application for it - reads the RFC. I personally never saw a CVS reader which handles multi-line texts. And the TC for example, also uses such tool - or this topic wont be created in the first place.

Comment: We even have two tags on this site, [tag:csv] for full-blown CSV data with fields that potentially embed newlines, quotes and commas, and [tag:csv-simple] for simple comma-delimited data.